# How to execute all views in database through stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, testing, stored-procedures

We have a problem with our table schema falling out of sync with our view schema. I would like to know how I could have a stored procedure (for Sql Server) that gets all views in the database, and executes each one via select *

Here is what I imagined (pseudo):

---

Declare x
Set x = Select object from sysobjects where object = view

foreach view in x
sp_execute 'select * from view'

---

We could then have an automated test that calls this every night. A SqlException would indicated that something was out of sync.

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: May I ask what, specifically, is occurring for you? Is it mostly that the column names are changing or the columns are being deleted, or SELECT * isn't picking up new columns, or what? And may I ask what the purpose of the views is? Are they there just as a permissions/abstraction layer or do they do additional joins and other business object assembly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

should work in 2000 and up

```
select quotename(table_schema) +'.' + quotename(table_name) as ViewNAme,
 identity(int,1,1) as ID
  into #test
  from information_schema.tables
 where table_type = 'view'


declare @Loopid int,@MaxID int


select @LoopID =1,@MaxID =MAX(id) 
from #test

declare @ViewName varchar(100)

while @LoopID <= @MaxID
begin

select @ViewName = ViewNAme 
from #test
where id = @LoopID

exec ('select top 1 * from ' + @ViewName)
set @LoopID = @LoopID + 1
end

drop table #test
```

I mostly focused on one part of your question, see also [how to make sure that the view will have the underlying table changes by using sp_refreshview](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-make-sure-that-the-view-will-have)

Comment: Not reliable though, is it...?

Comment: I specifically answered this part " I would like to know how I could have a stored procedure (for Sql Server) that gets all views in the database, and executes each one via select *"

Comment: @SQLMenace: Does it solve the problem? Should we not educate and improve?

Comment: Okay..added the refresh view link

Comment: Please throw a TOP 1 into that dynamic SQL :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd really suggest you use [WITH SCHEMABINDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) to prevent this happening.

Or use sp_refreshview in a loop at least.

`SELECT * FROM view` is not reliable: how do know if the output is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2008 you can use the following to detect unresolved dependencies without having to actually select from the view.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.views v
JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies e ON e.referencing_id = v.object_id
and  referenced_id is null
```

Comment: Created table with 1 field, created view for selecting that field, renamed field in table, executed your query, got an empty result set - not sure what this is supposed to do...

The accepted solution gives me the exception I am looking for.

Comment: @PAR - Yes this will get dropped tables. Just looking to see if it can be adjusted for dropped columns also. In any event `sp_refreshview` will get those without having to select everything